# Get query result from SQL Server and execute commands using Command Prompt

Tags: powershell, t-sql, command-line, powershell-4.0

I am working on PowerShell script which gets the data from SQL Server Audit table. As you can see in below query, I am getting the list of rows (contains command line command one line) that I need to execute.

```
$sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConn.ConnectionString = “Server=localhost;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=master”
$sqlConn.Open()

$Query = "select TabCommands from DatabaseName.dbo.PROCESSED_INTERCHANGES where IsUpdated = '1' "

$sqlConn.Close()
$sqlConn.Dispose()
```

How do I save the query result in memory or temp place and execute commands (refreshes Tableau Extract) in the following path?

```
C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\10.5\extras\Command Line Utility
```

I would do cursor in SQL but I am having issues with executing commands from SQL Server Management Studio so using PowerShell.

Comment: `Set-Location 'C:\Program Files\Tableau\Tableau Server\10.5\extras\Command Line Utility'` and simply execute the commands? It's not clear to me what problem you're facing.

Comment: $Query will give me the list of 50 to 200 rows (individual windows commands), how do I execute them from PowerShell one by one at given path.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I am looking something like this. While (rowcount > 0){ Execute 1; rowline ++}, Execute each row (result) one by one.

Comment: Well, first of all you'd need to actually execute the query. Then perhaps something like `$result.TabCommands | ForEach-Object { & $_ }`. For further help you need to provide more information about the query results.

Comment: So this needs to be automated, 
i

Comment: Please [edit] your question.

Comment: This needs to be automated so I can't run it manually. All command are Tableau Software utility so when I go to that path I can run it. It's same as you are executing command prompts command such as 1st line CD Desktop 2nd command CD Folder 3rd one Remove item etc.. You can execute one command at a time.